# Passsport authentication using express displays the information of previosly logged in user on a different machine. How to prevent it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I have a react application that uses passport authentication strategy using express server. In my local machine my set up will start a server (app.js) in one port and react app in other port. And I'm able to authenticate successfully using passport. In the hosting environment the server will take care of starting the server and building the react client to public folder.

My issue happens after I push my code to the hosting environment, the hosting environment starts the express server (node app.js) and build the react app to public folder. Even though I'm able to authenticate using passport and able to receive the user information, if someone else was logged in from a different browser of a different machine then that user's profile is available in my browser.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');        
...
let user = {}; //this is an object to store the profile data
...
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});
var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-ci-oidc').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
    clientID: settings.client_id,
    clientSecret: settings.client_secret,
    callbackURL: settings.callback_url,
    function (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            user = {...profile}
            profile.accessToken = accessToken;
            profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
            done(null, profile);
        })
    }
);

passport.use(Strategy);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {}));

app.get('/oidc_callback', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
        successRedirect: redirect_url,
        failureRedirect: '/failure',
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/user', function (req, res) {  //This is the api i use to access user information in ract page
  res.send(user);
});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    user = {};                         //empty the user data object
    req.session.destroy();
    req.logout();
    res.end();
});
```

Here we can see I'm using a `user` object to store the user data and created a API `/user` `(app.get('/user' ...)` to access the user data from my client react application.

**React component to access the user**

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      loggedUser: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/user')       //If I'm testing with local the API will be https://localhost:5000 - node server
      .then(res => {
        const loggedUser = res.data; 
        this.setState({ loggedUser });
      }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Fetch error", err)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** completely reviewed answer after question edited with new data.

First of all we need a unique key in `profile` to uniquely identify a user, in my example I use `"oid"` but you can use the one better fits your requirements.

You could try to change following pieces of code:

```
let user = {}; //this is an object to store the profile data

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

// Later ...
function(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        user = {...profile}
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        done(null, profile);
    })
}
```

with:

```
let uniqueKey = "oid"; // The field name of profile which uniquely identify a user
let users = {};

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, (users[user[uniqueKey]] = user)[uniqueKey]));
passport.deserializeUser((key, done) => done(null, users[key]));

// Later ...
(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) => done(null, { ...profile, accessToken, refreshToken })
// or
(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) => {
    process.nextTick(() => done(null, { ...profile, accessToken, refreshToken }));
}
```

All these are async functions, so when I say *to return* I mean doing it through the `done` callback function.

The *first login function* only need to return the `user` object (actually [passport-ci-oidc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ci-oidc) seems to require it in `process.nextTick`, you can try with or without it).

`serializeUser` needs indeed to *serialize* the user object, which in our case means just to sore it in the memory store `users[user[uniqueKey]] = user` and then to return the unique key which passport should later use to deserialize the same user `done(null, user[uniqueKey])`.

As last `deserializeUser` need to return the user object by a given identification key, in our case just to return it from the memory sore `done(null, users[key])`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I'm using passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser i did not include those in the question as it was obvious and did not want create a lengthy code in question..

Comment: Ok, but they are a key part of authentication flow, it could be that the source of your problem is in one of those functions. If you are still experiencing your problem it could be helpful to add them in your question.

Comment: Oh thanks i edited my question accordinglly .. thanks